# regroup contigous values with count in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a (postgres) table like this

```
 order     data     
 1         12,1
 2         12,1
 3         12,1
 4         13,4
 5         13,4
 6         12,1
 7         12,1 
 8         16
 9         16
```

i'd like to build a SQL statement which allows me to display
contigous values, with count.
Something like that..

```
 order     data     count     
 1         12,1     3
 4         13,4     2
 6         12,1     2
 8         16       2
```

Is there a way do that in (postgres) SQL ?

Comment: What does `12,1` mean? Is it two integer values (12 and 1), or is it 12.1, written with a decimal comma?

Comment: @jarlh it represents 12.1 with a decimal comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my query structure and result in: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6321f2f6fe9bdd75b18d7b51b671acfc)

```sql
with recursive
    cte_r as (
        select "order",
               data,
               row_number() over (order by "order") as rn
        from test
        order by "order", data),
    cte as (
        select "order",
               data,
               rn,
               rn as grp
        from cte_r
        where rn = 1
        union all
        select cr."order",
               cr.data,
               cr.rn,
               case
                   when c.data isnull or c.data = cr.data then c.grp
                   else c.grp + 1
                   end
        from cte c,
             cte_r cr
        where c.rn = cr.rn - 1
    )
select distinct first_value("order") over (w) as "order",
                data,
                count(*) over (w)
from cte
    window w as (partition by grp)
order by 1;
```

Comment: really fine answer. absolutly works perfectly !